# Optimising PHPMyAdmin configuration for massive databases and many tables

Tags: mysql, php, database, database-administration

Developers require database access to a significant number of databases, each with 220+ tables, and currently they are provided this using phpMyAdmin 2.11.9.5. Initial load is very slow, puts some load on the database cluster beneath, and runs lots of (needless) `SHOW TABLES FROM x` queries to gather data for *every* table in every datbase. Developers do not require this information in the left hand navigation pane, however this information is still required when they select that database.

There are [various options available](http://secure2.thisispearl.com/1231214/j8efdvsdf/238hnsvc/jju9sdadls/phpMyAdmin/Documentation.html#config) for configuring the installation, however none of them are obviously tailored to handle a colossal number of databases.

1. Can anybody recommend options on tuning phpMyAdmin to deal with many tables (`$cfg['ShowStats'] = false;` is the only obvious one)?
2. Is there any equivalent to phpMyAdmin tailored to very large deployments? Perhaps caching table meta data (there are memcached instances available) or not outputting such verbose information?
3. Does phpMyAdmin 3.2.0.1 suffer the same sluggish performance? Upgrading is a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would investigate upgrading to 3.2.0.1. There are a number of enhancements to the selects and being able to turn features on or off. Here's one I would look at http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#DisableIS as well as creating some custom selects in ShowDatabasesCommand

However 3.2.0.1 requires PHP 5.2 or better and Mysql 5.0.15 or better.